# Calculate Points from Letters in a Switch Case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to create a scrabble-like program that calculates the points of letters contained in a word. These word are contained in a .txt file. I can get it to read from the file, but unsure how to get it to calculate the value of each word. I have attached what I have done so far, and am wondering if a switch case is the best way to go, and if so, how do I assign a value to a letter with a switch case. Any help is appreciated.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project      Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
 package pointsproblem;

/**
 *
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

 public class PointsProblem {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    //create new object//        
    PointsProblem task1 = new PointsProblem();  

    File file = new File("dictionary.txt");  
    // read the file//
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    //check if file can be found//
    if (!file.isFile()) {
        System.err.println("Cannot open file: " + input);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Successfully opened file: " + input + ".");
    }   
    //read all the lines in the file//
   {
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String word = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(word);
            System.out.println("'" + input + "' is worth " + point + " points");



    int point = "";
    switch(point)  {


    case 'a': = "1":
    case 'e': = "1";
    case 'i': = "1";
    case 'l': = "1";
    case 'n': = "1";
    case 'o': = "1";
    case 'r': = "1";
    case 's': = "1";
    case 't': = "1";
    case 'u': = "1";
    case 'g': = "2";
    case 'g': = "2";
    case 'b': = "3";
    case 'm': = "3";
    case 'c': = "3";
    case 'p': = "3";
    case 'f': = "4";
    case 'h': = "4";
    case 'v': = "4";
    case 'w': = "4";
    case 'y': = "4";
    case 'k': = "5";
    case 'j': = "8";
    case 'x': = "8";
    case 'q': = "10";
    case 'z': = "10";                            

    return score  =  point + "";
        }//end switch

     }//end point calculation loop

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    //public boolean containsLetter(Character letter) {
        //return points.contains(letter);//

    }
```

I have tried assigning an int of X to the value as well. I would like it to read the word contained in the file and give a total score.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a `Map<Character, Integer>` would fit:

```
public class PointsProblem {
    final Map<Character, Integer> pointsMap = Map.of(
        'a', 1,
        'e', 1,
        //.......
        'z', 10
    );
```

Then, in your function, simply use the map to find the corresponding point for each character:

```
int wordPoints = 0;
for(char c : word.toCharArray())
    wordPoints += pointsMap.get(c);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. This seem much more tidy than what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the code you've shown us will compile. There are a few things you need to change;

1) You're setting a String to an int. You'll want to change that to

`int point = 0`

2) You aren't setting anything in the switch statement

Change `case 'a': = "1":` to `case 'a': point = 1;`

3) You will never set a unique value in the switch statement because you aren't using 'break'
Checkout this page for a good tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Basically without any break statements, your code will go through the of the statements and point will just be assigned to your last case
You want to have something along the lines of

```
switch(char)  {
    case 'a': point = 1;
        break;
    case 'e': point = 1;
        break;
    // etc.
    default: point = 1;  // maybe throw an error or add some logging for the default case
         break;
}
return point;
```

I am presuming that you actually have this switch statement in it's own method and not in main as you've shown us above, otherwise the return statement won't help you.
You can also shorten this so that each case simply returns a value (again, if this is in it's own method), i.e.

```
switch(char) {
    case 'a': return 1;
    case 'b': return 1;
    // etc.
}
```

---

edit:

The best way to get the point value of the whole word via a switch statement is:

```
char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
int point=0;
for (char c: chars) {
    switch(c) {
        case 'a':
            point += 1;
            break;
        // etc.
    }
}
System.out.println("Total point value of word '" + word + "' was " + point);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought if I had a break in my switch, it would not calculate the entire word as a total. I will start modifying my code.

Comment: You're right it won't calculate the entire word. What you want to do is run this switch statement on every character in your word, then manually add up the 'point' values. I'll modify my answer to help with this

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to store the values:

```
Map<Character, Integer> charValues = new HashMap();
charValues.put('a', 2);
charValues.put('b', 1);
```

You can use the chars() and collect as sum

```
int total = word.chars()
                .mapToObj(c -> charValues.get((char)c))
                .mapToInt(i -> (int)i)
                .sum();
```

But according to your use case you can count the chars first and then multiply

```
  Map<Character, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
  while (input.hasNext()) {
     String word = input.next();
     word.chars().forEach(c -> counter.compute(c, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1));
  }

counter.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .mapToInt(e -> charValues.get(e.getKey())*e.getValue())
       .sum();
```

if you are using switch your code will look like:

```
int total = 0;

switch (c){
      case 'a' : total += 1; break;
      case 'b' : total += 2; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning individually for each 'case' statement, you can also use the fall through feature of the switch block.

```
    int calcScore(String str)
    {
        int score = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
        switch(str.charAt(i))  {
            case 'a':  
            case 'e': 
            case 'i': 
            case 'l': 
            case 'n': 
            case 'o': 
            case 'r': 
            case 's': 
            case 't': 
            case 'u': score += 1; break;
            case 'g': score += 2; break;
            case 'b': 
            case 'm': 
            case 'c': 
            case 'p': score += 3; break;
            case 'f': 
            case 'h': 
            case 'v': 
            case 'w': 
            case 'y': score += 4; break;
            case 'k': score += 5; break;
            case 'j': 
            case 'x': score += 8; break;
            case 'q': 
            case 'z': score += 10; break;                          
            }
    }
        return score;
 }
```

This function can be called for each word.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with this:   switch (c) {

                    case 'a':
                    case 'e':
                    case 'i':
                    case 'l':
                    case 'n':
                    case 'o':
                    case 'r':
                    case 's':
                    case 't':
                    case 'u':
                        point += 1;
                        break;          etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I ended up with the following code which gives the output  I am after;

```
  System.out.println("Points problem");

             File file = new File("dictionary.txt");
    // read the file//
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    //check if file can be found//
    if (!file.isFile()) {
        System.err.println("Cannot open file: " + file);
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Successfully opened file: " + file + ".");
    }
    //read all the lines in the file//

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String word = input.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(word);
        int l = word.length();
        int point = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < l; x++) {
            char c = word.charAt(x);                
            switch (c) {

                case 'a':
                case 'e':
                case 'i':
                case 'l':
                case 'n':
                case 'o':
                case 'r':
                case 's':
                case 't':
                case 'u':
                    point += 1;
                    break;

                case 'd':
                case 'g':
                    point += 2;
                    break;

                case 'b':
                case 'c':
                case 'm':
                case 'p':
                    point += 3;
                    break;

                case 'f':
                case 'h':
                case 'v':
                case 'w':
                case 'y':
                    point += 4;
                    break;

                case 'k':
                    point += 5;
                    break;

                case 'j':
                case 'x':    
                    point += 8;
                    break;

                case 'q':                        
                case 'z':
                    point += 10;
                    break;                       
            }//end switch*/
        }//end point calculation loop         
        System.out.println(word + "is worth " + point + " points." );
    }
```